# ThreeJs, Panorama environment with ground

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a scene using Three.js with a panoramic picture environment and an object in the center like this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_envmaps).

The only problem is that the object here is floating in the middle of the scene.
I want to have it look like my object is standing on the ground. Like in this awesome [example](http://www.weber.com/US/en/genesis-ii/model/burner_4), it seems to be using a kind of [cubemap image](http://www.weber.com/US/en/genesis-ii/version/1492092316/data/webgl/background/backyardBeachHouse/ldr_specular.png) layout.

How can i achieve this? if i simply place the object on the 'ground' of my cubemap or spherical environment the view gets badly distorted.

Comment: The reference page is no longer there, however, the cube map referred to can be viewed here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180425061935/http://www.weber.com/US/en/genesis-ii/version/1492092316/data/webgl/background/backyardBeachHouse/ldr_specular.png

I have the same question, too bad nobody has answered it yet.

Comment: @ThreeDFish did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @MThomas We ended up adding a mesh for the ground level that extends past the cube map